# Keyboard height not working properly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, uiresponder

I am using below code to adjust current view when keyboard is showing and hiding. When keyboard is showing the code works, but when its hiding the view moving slidely bottom keeping a black space at the top. **How to resolve it?**

```
@objc func keyboardWillAppear(notification: Notification){
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardHeight/2
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification){
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        self.view.frame.origin.y = +keyboardHeight/2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the view instead of assigning to origin

```
@objc func keyboardWillAppear(notification: Notification){
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -keyboardHeight/2)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification){
        self.view.transform = .identity
}
```

Comment: Thanks it solved. But what was the root cause of the issue in my approach?

Comment: actually this is the  first time to face this but seems changing values to origin changes the frame.size of  a UIView so when you minimized y axis it cuts the view by that value